# What is a $\chi^2$-test?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I solved part (a) of this problem but I don't understand what a $\chi^2$ test is in part (b) (Wikipedia did not help me):

> Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with pdf
>   $f(x)=\theta x^{\theta-1}$, for $0<x\leq1$ and $\theta>0$. We want to
>   test the hypothesis $H_0:\theta\leq5$ against $H_1:\theta>5$.
>
> (a) Show that the likelihood-ratio test rejects $H_0$ when $-\sum\log X_i$ is too small.
>
> (b) Show that the test in (a) is equivalent to a $\chi^2$ test.

Comment: [Chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test).

Comment: (Assuming that your Wikipedia problem was that you couldn't find the right article, that is).

Comment: @wircho The $\chi^2$-test in part b is the Pearson's $\chi^2$-test ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test)-article). This is slightly more technical than the page Henning links to

Comment: Thanks Sasha! But how does one prove that this is a Pearson's $\chi^2$ test? I don't see any relation.

Comment: Can you show us what you did for part a) it might be easier to see what the problem is if we can see where you got to and how.